Threebox , displaying a 3D model on a react-map-gl component
So i am trying to use threebox text to display a 3d model on a 3d map from mapbox. Here is my code for now :"
import "./InteractiveMap.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { API } from "../../api";
import LocationOnIcon from "@mui/icons-material/LocationOn";
import { Container } from "@mui/material";
import CancelIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Cancel";
import Map, {
  Marker,
  NavigationControl,
  Popup,
  GeolocateControl,
} from "react-map-gl";
import "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import DefaultPopupContent from "./DefaultPopupContent";
import TasksPopupContent from "./TasksPopupContent";
import { Threebox } from "threebox-plugin";
import * as THREE from "three";

export default function InteractiveMap({ userId }) {
  const [clusters, setClusters] = useState([]);
  const [currentPlaceId, setCurrentPlaceId] = useState(null);
  const [plots, setPlots] = useState([]);
  const [selectedRow, setSelectedRow] = useState(null);
  const [popupContent, setPopupContent] = useState("default");
  const [userCity, setUserCity] = useState(null);
  const [viewPort, setViewPort] = useState({
    longitude: 11.598,
    latitude: 48.143,
    zoom: 10.81,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getClusters() {
      try {
        const response = await API.get("/clusters");
        setClusters(response.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error fetching clusters:", err);
      }
    }
    getClusters();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchUserCity() {
      try {
        const userResponse = await API.get(`/users/${userId}`);
        const user = userResponse.data;
        if (user.city) {
          const cityResponse = await API.get(`/cities/${user.city}`);
          const city = cityResponse.data;
          setViewPort({
            longitude: city.lon,
            latitude: city.lat,
            zoom: 10.81,
          });
          setUserCity(city);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching user or city information:", error);
        setViewPort({
          longitude: 11.598,
          latitude: 48.143,
          zoom: 10.81,
        });
      }
    }

    if (userId) {
      fetchUserCity();
    }
  }, [userId]);

  async function fetchPlotsByClusterId(clusterId) {
    try {
      const response = await API.get(`/clusters/${clusterId}/plots`);
      if (response.data && response.data.plots) {
        const plotsWithId = response.data.plots.map((plot, index) => ({
          ...plot,
          id: index + 1,
        }));
        setPlots(plotsWithId);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Failed to fetch plots:", err);
    }
  }

  function handleRowClick(params) {
    if (selectedRow && params.row.id === selectedRow.id) {
      setSelectedRow(null);
    } else {
      setSelectedRow(params.row);
    }
  }

  function handleMarkerClicked(id) {
    setCurrentPlaceId(id);
    fetchPlotsByClusterId(id);
  }

  function handleUpdateClick() {
    setPopupContent("updated");
  }

  function handleUpdateClick2() {
    setPopupContent("default");
  }

  function handleButtonClick() {
    console.log("Button clicked with row:", selectedRow);
  }

  function validateNumeric(value, name) {
    if (value === null || value === undefined || isNaN(value)) {
      console.error(`Invalid value for ${name}:`, value);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  return (
    <Container maxWidth={false} disableGutters>
      {viewPort && (
        <Map
          container={"map"}
          projection={"globe"}
          initialViewState={viewPort}
          mapboxAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_TOKEN}
          style={{ width: "100vw", height: "93vh" }}
          mapStyle="mapbox://styles/young-beetle/clx2djvn401nx01pn74163bnx"
          antialias={true}
          onLoad={(event) => {
            console.log("Map loaded");
            const map = event.target;
            const tb = new Threebox(map, map.getCanvas().getContext("webgl"), {
              defaultLights: true,
            });
            console.log("Threebox initialized");
            window.tb = tb;

            map.addLayer({
              id: "custom_layer",
              type: "custom",
              renderingMode: "3d",
              onAdd: function (map, mbxContext) {
                console.log("Custom layer onAdd called");

                const options = {
                  obj: `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/Soldier.glb`,
                  type: "gltf",
                  scale: 1,
                  units: "meters",
                  rotation: { x: 90, y: 0, z: 0 }, //default rotation
                };

                console.log("Loading model with options:", options);

                tb.loadObj(options, function (model) {
                  const coords = [viewPort.longitude, viewPort.latitude];
                  if (
                    validateNumeric(coords[0], "longitude") &&
                    validateNumeric(coords[1], "latitude")
                  ) {
                    const soldier = model.setCoords(coords);
                    tb.add(soldier);
                    console.log("Model added to Threebox");
                  }
                });
              },
              render: function (gl, matrix) {
                tb.update();
              },
            });
          }}
        >
          
        </Map>
      )}
    </Container>
  );
}

So i added a lot of logging and there is normally no problem with the Soldier file and with the path  for it as when i try on the browser when i try to get the resource it is working . as it is the first example that is in the documentation of threebox. It would be nice if someone with expertise or knows how to do this can help me here.
I was expecting for the 3D model to be displayed but it is not and the logging i did says that it should work but it doesn't...
